# What does baller mean on Match Attax cards?

Tags: meaning

In the trading cards for association football made by Match Attax, some players are described as ballers. See https://www.footballcardsdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/EPLMAE1819-BL01.jpeg for example.  This must be in British English.

What does it mean?

Comment: It means someone who plays (a ball sport) and is very successful at it.

Comment: @Robusto Have you seen this use anywhere else? I can't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: It looks like a category invented by the designers of Match Attax, rather like a suit in conventional playing cards. I don't think that it has widespread use in the UK, I've never seen or heard it to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak specifically to your Match Attax cards, but *baller* is a term familiar in the US, which may have floated across the pond to you and been picked up by the producer of those cards. I believe it originated with basketball (I recall hearing it in that context over the years) but it was adopted wholeheartedly by (American) football.

TFD Online gives [this definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/baller):

> **baller** *n*
>   1. (Ball Games, other than specified) *slang* a ball-game player, esp in basketball

It has enough currency that HBO turned it into (at last count) a five-season program (see [Ballers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2891574/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_12)).

I do recall hearing *ball* used as a verb (which is how *baller* might have come into being) in the 1997 movie [*Any Given Sunday*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146838/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1) in which the lead character, played by Jamie Foxx, compares himself to someone by saying "But can he ball?" Note that this could be a double-entendre, since ball has long been a slang term for performing coitus.

> **ball** *v.tr.* [also *v.intr.*]
>   2. Vulgar Slang To have sexual intercourse with.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ball)</sub>

Comment: Match Attax cards are made by Topps which is an American company. They probably don't realise that we don't call ball players "ballers" and just carried the term over from their other card sets.

Comment: In US English does it mean the player is particularly good at the sport? Otherwise it's pretty meaningless to label someone playing football as a baller.

Comment: @Anush: It definitely suggests an elite player.